# Is it normal I receive these error messages closing my Flutter app in debug mode?

Tags: flutter

When I close my Flutter app in debug mode with back button I read in console window:

```
D/EGL_emulation( 3019): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3d0d0a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8ac94890)
D/EGL_emulation( 3019): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3d0c140: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8c798b60)
E/libEGL  ( 3019): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
D/FlutterLocationService( 3019): Unbinding from location service.
D/FlutterLocationService( 3019): Destroying service.
```

Are those messages and that OpenGL error normal?

Comment: I think these are just logs,

Answer (score 1):

```
D/FlutterLocationService( 3019): Unbinding from location service.
D/FlutterLocationService( 3019): Destroying service.
```

I see them too when I quit the app by pressing back button. In my case, I have Google Maps along with location services activated in my app. It's normal. Don't know anything about the OpenGL thing.